# SCCM/MDT Laptop with Ethernet in Docking

Tags: sccm, mdt

We're trying to deploy a Lenovo L380 Yoga with a Lenovo docking connected over USB with SCCM/MDT.
The reason for the docking is because this laptop doesn't have an onboard NIC.

The SCCM driver package has been loaded into LiteTouch.
https://support.lenovo.com/us/nl/downloads/ds502364
But once LiteTouch is launched, the lights on the NIC go out and we get the message:

> "A connection to the deployment share could not be made. Check
>   Physical connection".

We're sure that the physical connection to the server is okay because we're able to download the LiteTouch file from it, also we see a DHCP entry for the laptop.

We're sure this is not an USB driver issue because the mouse (connected to the dock or connected to the laptop) works.

Only the NIC on the docking doesn't seem to work once LiteTouch has booted.
We have however loaded the NIC drivers in the SCCM package into LiteTouch.

Is there any other way to check what's wrong?

Comment: Have you included the NIC driver in the boot image you are using?

Comment: Yes, the SCCM package provided the USB3 and NIC drivers downloaded here: https://support.lenovo.com/be/nl/downloads/ds502364.

Comment: If you've definitely injected the driver into the boot image then the best way to diagnose what's going wrong is to check the SMSTS.log file. You'll need to enable command support for your boot image (from the Customization tab of the boot image properties) if you haven't already done so. When the error occurs press F8 and you will get a command prompt from which you can access the log file. Check the link below for log file locations. Hope this helps

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30109.sccm-how-to-copy-smsts-log-when-a-task-sequence-fails.aspx